# bipartite graph with t vertices in each partition

Tags: graphs

[image: The Figure that want draw]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and 21mm,
      start chain = going below,
        V/.style = {circle, draw, 
        fill=#1, 
        inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3mm,
        node contents={}},
 every fit/.style = {ellipse, draw=#1, inner ysep=-1mm, inner xsep=5mm},]
% vertices 
\foreach \i in {0,...,3} 
{
\ifnum\i=0
    \node (n2\i) [V, above right=0.001mm and 22mm of n1\i,
    label={right:$z_{\i}$}];
\else
    \node (n2\i) [V, above right=0.001mm and 22mm of n1\i,
    label={right:$z_{\i}$}];
    \node (n1\i) [V,
    on chain
    ,label={left:$y_{\i}$}];
\fi
}

% Conjunto U_1
\node [fit=(n11) (n13),label=above:$I$] {};
% Conjunto U_2
\node [fit=(n20) (n23),label=above:$S-I$] {};

\draw [->,shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm]
        (n20) edge (n11) 
        (n11) edge (n21)
        (n21) edge (n12)
        (n22) edge (n13)
        (n12) edge (n22)
        (n13) edge (n23);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

I need draw this graph with t vertices in partition I and t+1 vertices in partition S-I. Below as shown the figure.  Anyone who can help I will be grateful!

Comment: Any news? Does my answer fit your expectation? If it, it will be nice from you to accept it (by clicking on check mark at to left side of answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 21mm,
  start chain = going below,
     U/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1,
                inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3mm, 
                node contents={}},
     V/.style = {U, on chain},
every edge/.style = {decoration={markings,
                                 mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{Straight Barb}}},
                     draw, postaction={decorate}
                     },
                    ]
% vertices
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,2,3}%
{
    \node (n1\j) [V,label=left:{$y_{\i}$}];
    \node (n2\j) [U,above right=of n1\j, label=right:{$z_{\j}$}];
}
    \node (n23) [U,right=of n12, label=right:{$z_{3}$}];
    \node (n13) [on chain]      {$\vdots$};
    \node (n24) [right=of n13]  {$\vdots$};
    \node (n14) [V,label=left:{$z_{t}$}];
    \node (n25) [U,right=of n14, label=right:{$z_{t}$}];
%
\node [above=1mm of n10 |- n20, label=left:$I$] {}; 
\node [above=1mm of n20, label=right:{$S/I$}] {};
% connections 
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1,2,3}%
{
\draw   (n2\j) edge (n1\j) 
        (n1\j) edge (n2\i);
}
\draw   (n14) edge (n25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```